# Project facet Cloud Foundry Standalone Application version 1.0 is not supported

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat

I am trying to start a spring starter project. After creating the project, I am suppose to go into the pom.xml file and give the packaging tag of type 'war'.

`<groupId>org.test</groupId>
 artifactId>demo</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>war</packaging>`

I then update the Maven project and then proceed to add the project to the tomcat server. However, I am getting this error:

`Project facet Cloud Foundry Standalone Application version 1.0 is not supported.`

What can be the problem? Also note that I have done this before and it didn't work. I tried it again and it was able to work. Now that I am on a different system, it doesn't work again. I am also following the Introduction to Spring MVC 4 tutorial

Comment: For some reason, it worked again. The second time I did it I created the project, changed the packaging to war, and then added the tomcat server, and then added the project to the server. It works. First time I added the tomcat server first and did the rest, which resulted in the error. What can this mean?

Answer (score 2):

Had the exact same issue in Spring STS.

To resolve: 
a. in STS  right click project root (project name)-> click properties -> Search for "Project
    Facets",  and **uncheck** "**Cloud Foundry standalone Application**"  and press OK

b. right click project root (project name) again -> Maven -> Update Project (shortcut Alt+F5)

c. you will then be able to add the project to the server

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Remove the Clound Foundary Standalone Application version 1.0 facet from the project via project -> properties -> project facets.